# I want to insert multiple rows into SQL Server database, but get syntax errors

Tags: c#, sql-server, syntax-error, union-all

I want to insert multiple pieces of data into a SQL Server database as shown below, but when I run this code, I get a syntax error

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'union'.
>   Incorrect syntax near ''.
>   Incorrect syntax near ''.
>   Incorrect syntax near ''.

Code:

```
SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [rampDB].[dbo].[Answers]([AssessmentID],[questionID],[result],[comment]) SELECT('"
        + assessmentid + "1.1a" + RadioButtonList1.SelectedItem.Value.ToString() + TextBox1.Text + "'union'"
        + "'SELECT'" + assessmentid + "1.1b" + RadioButtonList2.SelectedItem.Value.ToString() + TextBox2.Text + "'union'"
        + "'SELECT'" + assessmentid + "1.1c" + RadioButtonList3.SelectedItem.Value.ToString() + TextBox3.Text + "'union'"
        + "'SELECT'" + assessmentid + "1.1d" + RadioButtonList4.SelectedItem.Value.ToString() + TextBox4.Text + "'union'"
        + "'SELECT'" + assessmentid + "1.1e" + RadioButtonList5.SelectedItem.Value.ToString() + TextBox5.Text
        + "')", sqlConn);
```

Comment: Please post the actual string you are passing to the SQL Command (with all the variables replaced).  In other words, rewrite the code to build the SQL statement into a temporary variable:
String temp = "INSERT INTO ...." + ...

Then put that SQL statement into the question instead.

Comment: a) Try printing out the actual SQL command.  We can only guess what is in those variables; b) Use prepared statements.  This code is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: Also, please give your input fields names. `TextBox3` isn't a good name.

Comment: You need commas and spaces in your statement, you've run it all together

Comment: Anything could be entered into "textbox", so a user could wreak havoc on your application.

Comment: There's lack of spaces and single quotes all over the place. Best option is to write a line after the one you have above like this: System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(cmd2.CommandText)    This will show you what you are doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple-insert syntax for SQL Server is possible with only `INSERT`, like so:

```
INSERT INTO rampDB.dbo.Answers (
    assessmentID, QuestionId, Result, Comment
) VALUES
( @r1v1, @r1v2, @r1v3, @r1v4 ),
( @r2v1, @r2v2, @r2v3, @r2v4 ),
( @r3v1, @r3v2, @r3v3, @r3v4 )
```

That said, the best way is to use a single `INSERT` with parameters, which is then executed for each row.

Answer (score 0):

Relpace "'union'" with this--> "union"